# Problems with Spring-security

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I need your help with `spring-security`. I have a repository with the code of my application in which I want to try to make spring-sequrity for authorization and authentication. The fact is that when I run a project, the terminal gives this error:

`The dependencies of some of the beans in the application context form a cycle:`
`sequrityConfiguration (field private org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService com.social_app_backend.config.SequrityConfiguration.userDetailsService)`
`userServiceImpl defined in file [J:\backend_for_social_app\target\classes\com\social_app_backend\service\UserServiceImpl.class]`

I used to run this code easily and it worked great. Tell me, what am I doing wrong, where is my mistake? Here is the repository, branch: `connectingToDatabaseWithSequrity`

SecurityConfiguration.java

```
package com.social_app_backend.config;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SequrityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

   @Autowired
   private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

   @Override
   protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
       auth.authenticationProvider(daoauthenticationProvider());
   }

   @Bean
   public AuthenticationProvider daoauthenticationProvider() {
     DaoAuthenticationProvider daoAuthenticationProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
     daoAuthenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
     daoAuthenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
     return daoAuthenticationProvider;
   }

   @Bean
   public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
       return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
   }

   @Override
   protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
   http.csrf().disable().cors().disable()
           .authorizeRequests()
           .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/registrate")
           .anonymous()
           .anyRequest().authenticated().and().httpBasic();
  }
}
```

UserServiceImpl.java

```
package com.social_app_backend.service;

import com.social_app_backend.dao.UserDao;
import com.social_app_backend.dto.UserDto;
import com.social_app_backend.entity.User;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService, UserService {

   private final UserDao userDao;
   private final PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

   @Override
   public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
    return userDao.findByUsername(username);
   }


   @Override
   public String createUser(UserDto userDto) {
    User user = new User();
    user.setUsername(userDto.getUsername());
    user.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(userDto.getPassword()));
    user.setRole("ROLE_USER");
    userDao.save(user);
    return user.getUsername();
   }
}
```

Comment: The following things can be removed: you dont need to set the `authenticationProvider` manually, you dont need to create the `DaoAuthenticationProvider` manually. These things will be done automatically

Answer (score 0):

From the code, it seems that the Circular dependency is getting formed as you have used `PasswordEncoder` in `UserServiceImpl` as well as in `SecurityConfig` So, for creating `SecurityConfig`, Spring needs `UserServiceImpl` bean and `UserServiceImpl` needs `PasswordEncoder` defined in `SecurityConfig`. 
To remove the cycle, create a separate Configuration class with `@Configuration`, shift the PasswordEncoder bean creation in that config, and autowire it in `SequrityConfiguration` as well as `UserServiceImpl`

Update:
You can do it Like below:

```
@Configuration
public class MyConfiguration{

   @Bean
   public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
       return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
   }

}
```

In SecurityConfig class,

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SequrityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

   @Autowired
   private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

   @Autowired
   private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;
....

   @Bean
   public AuthenticationProvider daoauthenticationProvider() {
     DaoAuthenticationProvider daoAuthenticationProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
     daoAuthenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
     daoAuthenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
     return daoAuthenticationProvider;
   }

}
```

Comment: I managed to do it,thank you. I have only one question, can you show or tell me how to set validation pattern to password??? Thank you)

Comment: If the answer is the solution, please accept or upvote it for the benefit of others. You can ask the validation pattern as a separate question.